# Laravel Eloquent -- Multiple record insertion in a table (with a column with unique constraint)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, multiple-insert

I have a table named 'categories' with uniqueness constraint on 'category_name' in my application, I want to inset multiple rows in 'categories'.

Bad Solution:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
   Category::firstOrCreate(array('category_name' => $category['name']));
}
```

This can be a solution but this is not a good one.The issue is when there will be hunders or thousands of record, this will make a lot of queries to database. which is not good.

Comparativel berter Solution

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cats[] = array('category_name' => $category['name']);
}
Category::insert($cats);
```

But when I try to insert a duplicate 'category_name', it throws an exception and none of category name is inserted.

I know that we can use `INSERT IGNORE` but I'm looking for some build in laravel solution.

Comment: Just wondering, why would you have category name unique? Is it one level only category mechanism? Or trying to store category with parent/child relationship?

Comment: to make it simple, I just want one level category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it won't be possible because in 2nd case one query will be executed so even if you catch any error no data will be inserted because SQL server refuse it because of unique constraint. I don't think Laravel can handle it.

Probably something like this is compromise to solve it quicker:

```
foreach($categories as $category){
   $names[] = $category['name']
}

$dups = Category::whereIn('name', $names)->lists('name');

if ($dups) {
  // here you can log or display message that some categories won't be inserted
}

$namesIns = [];
$cat = [];
foreach($categories as $category){
    $item = ['category_name' => $category['name']];
    if (!in_array($category['name'], $dups) && !in_array($item, $cat)) {
      $cat[] = $item;
      $namesIns[] = $category['name'];
    }
}
Category::insert($cat);

$ids = Category::whereIn('name', $namesIns)->lists('id');
```

Comment: `lists` is what you want instead of `pluck`, which returns only single row.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. But can we get ids of new inserted rows?

Comment: @MuhammadSaud You could get them if you inserted records one by one using `Category::create` inside loop. Otherwise using `insert` method I think you cannot get them. Of course you could run another query to get ids in your database for data you inserted

Comment: Yes, but loop will create issues when inserting too many rows. Running another query to get ids seems a better solution. Can you tell me which query will return the ids of the last insertion?

Comment: @MuhammadSaud I've updated my code, in `$ids` variable you should have array of inserted ids

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Sorry for the delay, This works perfectly fine for me. Thanks for your help. :)